# Image Buttons Zoomed In/Cropped On Layout?

Tags: android, xml, image, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm working on an app where I have 4 image buttons, but for some reason the images I use get very zoomed in / cropped, as can be seen below. Any suggestions?
[image]

I've tried resizing the image files themselves, but no matter whether they're 2k or 100x100, there's very little visual difference.

Here's the XML layout code for one of the buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="520dp"
    android:onClick="Click1"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/placeholder1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ImageButton` tag set attribute to

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: That's precisely what I was missing. Feels so silly spending hours when it's such a simple solution.Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yeah, it happens with every developer. cheers !!